# regex not working in python

Tags: python, regex

I am working on writing a regex for phonenumber. I have made a very basic regex for matching a phone number.

```
^[-+[:blank:][:digit:]]*$.
```

But that one in not working in python. If I try the same regex on someother tool for example text edit for regex search then its working. I am pretty new to regex so will be great if I can get some help.

Thanks

Comment: what are the exact allowed chars in your phone number other than digits?

Comment: Does Python support `[:blank:][:digit:]`? If not, you may want to replace them with `[-+ \d]`.

Comment: It only allows - and +

Comment: Is there supposed to be a period at the end of the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this (say your allowed phone no length is 10 to 15 digits):

`/^[0-9\-\+\s]{10,15}$/`

.

This will allow in:

1) numbers (0-9)

2) space

3) dash sign "-"

4) plus sign "+"

This is not a strict enforcing. To have exact strict format, you may need to alter as per your need.

Comment: Additional information: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax is a good way to start, for instance `+` is an operator and must be escaped ;)

Comment: I did that but since I am new to stackoverflow and my reputation is just 1 so I cant voteup. :(

Comment: @Torxed, the plus sign doesn't need escaping when it's inside a character class.  Neither does the hyphen, if you place it carefully.  `[0-9+\s-]` works just fine.

Comment: @AlanMoore what do you know, it works :) Thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: escaping doesnt cause any error. Even if not needed, its better to use it just to be sure.